# Installing Django to Windows 8.1

Tags: python, django, pip

I have been following this tutorial (https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_installation/) to learn some python but I have become stuck at the 'Django installation' step. I have managed to create a virtual environment and the .txt file but trying

```
(myvenv) (base) PS C:\users\JD\djangogirls> pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I get the error 'could not find version that satisfies requirement'and'no matching distribution found'. This error occurs when I have entered versions 2.2.4 & 3.0.5 of Django into the .txt file.

Have also just tried 'pip install django' and have come across the same errors.
Have tried in the windows command prompt but i get an error stating pip is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I have python 3.7.6 installed.

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: Show full traceback of your error, also which python version have you installed

Comment: I have installed python 3.7.6.

Comment: (myvenv) (base) PS C:\users\JD\djangogirls> pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: edit your question instead of placing it in comments

Comment: could you type in python -v while running your virtualenvironemnt

Comment: typed it in and now all i'm left with in the command-line is >>>

Comment: python --version

Comment: NameError@ name 'python' is not defined

Comment: You have to exit python console with exit() first also I would suggest reading about python prior to starting with Django

Comment: The problem is that your `pip` is for Python 2. The Django girls tutorial and the Python docs suggest that you use `python -m pip` instead of `pip` to avoid this problem. In your case, try `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`. Before running that command, make sure your prompt is `C:\users\JD\djangogirls>`. If it's `>>>`, then exit python first as iklinac says.

Comment: Thank you for your response. sadly I still have the same 2 errors coming up

Answer (score -1):

After enabling your virtualenv follow to following code

> pip install django==2.2.2

Add django==2.2.2 in requirements.txt

> pip install -r reqirements.txt

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Still getting the same errors after trying both inputs. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django==2.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from  versions:none) & ERROR: No matching distribution found for django==2.2.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))

Comment: what is your python version

Comment: I have python version 3.7.6 installed